# mongoid index still resulting in a COLLSCAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a simple class with a simple index

```
class A
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :value
    index({value: 1})
```

at the command line, I reindex

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

But when I run a simple query in the rails console

```
A.where(value: "1").to_a
```

The mongodb log clearly shows a COLLSCAN

```
command test_development.a command: find { find: "a", filter: { value: "1" }, 
$db: "test_development", lsid: { id: UUID("fa470127-398a-4f06-9a17-57b058017cf7") } }   
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:816688 cursorExhausted:1 
numYields:6380 nreturned:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

update - added additional information:

```
db.case_data.getIndexSpecs()
[
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "simple_development.case_data"
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_fts" : "text",
                    "_ftsx" : 1
            },
            "name" : "value_text",
            "ns" : "simple_development.case_data",
            "weights" : {
                    "value" : 1
            },
            "default_language" : "english",
            "language_override" : "language",
            "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

output of explain:

```
db.case_data.find({value: "test"}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "simple_development.case_data",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "value" : {
                            "$eq" : "test"
                    }
            },
            "queryHash" : "7E4E9C25",
            "planCacheKey" : "7E4E9C25",
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                            "value" : {
                                    "$eq" : "test"
                            }
                    },
                    "direction" : "forward"
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "msc-2",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "4.2.8",
            "gitVersion" : "43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Verify indexes are created, include current index listing in question and include a complete and readable query plan in question.

Comment: can you help me understand "current index listing" and how do i get the query plan, is it just .explain ?

Comment: I don't think this is a mongoid question. 
Can you add the result for the following command in mongo-shell: `db.getCollection(<collection_name>).getIndexSpecs()`
And also the result of `db.getCollection(<collection_name>).find({value: "1").explain()`

It will to understand the issue

Comment: @UdiCohen addded requested information.  the query takes about 15 seconds b/c it has to go through 800K records, hoping this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some combination of Mongoid 7.1.1 and mongodb 4.2.9, the rake task and the mongorestore both do not actually recreate indexes.  They say they do, but they do not.

This command results in COLLSCANs:

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

Using either mongo console to make index, or in each model, in a Rails console, doing:

```
A.remove_indexes
A.create_indexes
```

results in no COLLSCANs.

I've repeated this scientifically with clean db restores, and can say with certainty that the rake command and the mongorestore command do not recreate indexes.  My solution above fixes the issue.

Thanks to everyone for your help,
Kevin

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4802?focusedCommentId=3133160&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-3133160 update the rails version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the index was created like that, maybe it is because you didn't specify the field's type in the model class. Try to specify the type of the field, then manually drop the index in mongo shell `db.getCollection('X').dropIndex('value_text')`, and then run the rake for creating indices `rake db:create_indexes`.

If that doesn't work I would drop the index and manually create one in mongo shell `db.getCollection('X').createIndex({'value': 1}, {name: 'value_1', background: true})` (or wait for a better answer  )

Comment: I tried to define a field without specifying the type and the index was created as expected so maybe it's a mongoid version issue (I use version 7.1)